# Who/what calls CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

In his video tutorail

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/

the author goes to the Codegnitor web site. At first (**1:32**) the site looks strange (like it did not have any CSS behind it), but when he refreshes it once more the site looks like it should (**1:37**).

Does anyone know what is the mechanism behind it? I guess that JavaScript calls CSS. Can anyone give me some more details/examples.

Namely I would like to have my site working just like that.

Comment: I googled "How does CSS work" and found this link to the Mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/How_CSS_works
It seems to have more information for what you're looking for

Comment: This is not a Tut's site..Can ask your query to tutsplus..

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know the question is far too easy for this forum. Plus I did not even see your answers as I was expecting an e-mail notice about it. That is why I'm answering with a few days delay. Sorry for taking your time but I realy did not know where else to turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS gets activated by 2 possible methods.

1. Invocation by DOM when the html file is parsed.
2. Invocation of CSS forcefully by JavaScript's functions.

On this video second method has been used.

Comment: Thank you for answering, even though I know its an off-topic question.

Comment: Vikram Tiwari, is there any good tutorial on the web on how to do that (secondoption:Invocating CSS forcefully by Java Script). I promise I've tried to find something on my own but with no result. I just need a starting point. Then I will study it all on my own. No off-topic questions anymore ;)

Comment: @user2729096 a simple query on stackoverflow would give you a lot of answers. That way you can relate it to the usage as well.

Comment: Ok. I will. Actually I allready did ;) Thanks.